# Is "MA Graduation in Tourism Management with a concentration on Marketing" right?

Tags: phrase-request

I have finished my MA. I would like to add a life-event on my Facebook timeline. Is the title **"MA Graduation in Tourism Management with a concentration on Marketing"** right?

Comment: I don't like "concentration" at all. Maybe "emphasis on marketing" or "focus on marketing". "Concentration" implies a picture of you with a frowning phase full of concentration of the subject.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to describe the event of graduating, that sentence makes even less sense, because **MA** doesn't modify **graduation**. You want "Graduation with an MA in Tourism Management with a concentration in Marketing" or "Graduation from my Masters program with an MA in...."

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is:

> MA **Graduate** in Tourism Management with a concentration on Marketing

if you are describing your education.

Comment: The grade of the only module left to finish my MA was published today.

Comment: But are you describing yourself, or your graduation (passing the test/final class or such)?

Comment: A concentration *in* Marketing would be the conventional U.S. usage, to my ear.

Comment: @Juya, if you want to describe the event of graduating, that sentence makes even less sense.  You want "Graduation with an MA in Tourism Management with a concentration in Marketing" or "Graduation from my Masters program with an MA in...."  __MA__ doesn't modify __graduation__.

Comment: Would "with focus on Marketing" sound non-native?

Comment: @choster I am describing my graduation.

Comment: @Codeswitcher Why don't you write an answer pal so that I can pick it as the right answer?

Comment: Ah, I hadn't seen you'd answered my question about which you were trying to say.  Done.